# How can I resize an image without losing quality?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, image-quality

I have to place an Illustrator file into another one and then resize it (way smaller). How do I do that and keep a clear image?

Comment: Are you working with raster files in Illustrator files? Vector files do not "lose quality" unless you rasterize the file. Vector files are just mathematical points used to create objects, they will scale to any size.

Comment: Acutally it is a photoshop file into a illustrator file, so I guess it is a raster file, right ?

Comment: Yes unless you're importing paths from Photoshop to Illustrator. Photoshop is a raster program so files up scaled into Illustrator will become pixelated. There is no way to perfectly upscale images without losing quality as Photoshop or whatever program will be "creating pixels" to make the image larger.

Answer (score 1):

If the file you're placing isn't too complex, you could just copy the paths in that file and paste them into the other.

You can also do File->Place and place the illustrator file. It should retain quality as Illustrator is a vector program, and you're placing one vector file into another. This will link the file, so if you go to Window->Links, it should give you a window that shows all linked files (similar to InDesign) and you can "Update Links" when you update the placed file. This is convenient if you're doing print layouts and need to have the logo saved elsewhere.

Hope that helps!